# How do I center forms inside a table?

Tags: html, css, forms, html-table

The below code works for what I need (three horizontal buttons), except it is not centered. It sits on the left side of the screen. I did some research and couldn't fix it, and also tried a tableless design using "float" and "display:inline" and just can't get it centered. Help please!

```
<table>
<td>
<tr>
<form method="get" action="index.php"><button type="submit">Home</button></form>
<form method="get" action="signup"><button type="submit">Create Account</button></form>
<form method="get" action="login"><button type="submit">Login to Account</button></form>
</tr>
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using tables for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other people mentioned `<td>` should be inside `<tr>`. By default `<form>` is displayed as block element. Change it to `inline-block`.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}
form {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form method="get" action="index.php">
        <button type="submit">Home</button>
      </form>
      <form method="get" action="signup">
        <button type="submit">Create Account</button>
      </form>
      <form method="get" action="login">
        <button type="submit">Login to Account</button>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<tr>` (rows) should be on the outside

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form method="get" action="index.php"><button type="submit">Home</button></form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form method="get" action="signup"><button type="submit">Create Account</button></form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form method="get" action="login"><button type="submit">Login to Account</button></form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/g74z688n/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Inverse the `tr` and `td` in the html.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<form method="get" action="index.php"><button type="submit">Home</button></form>
</td>
<td>
<form method="get" action="signup"><button type="submit">Create Account</button></form>
</td>
<td>
<form method="get" action="login"><button type="submit">Login to Account</button></form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And try adding this to css

```
 td {
     text-align: center;
 }
```

And don't forget to set the width of your table ! (100% for all the window)